# When does the booted() method of an Eloquent model get called?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to add a simple closure-based global query scope:

```
// Order.php

protected static function booted()
{
    dd('here');
    static::addGlobalScope('test', function ($query) {
        $query->where('amount', '>', 50);
    });
}
```

However, when I execute `Order::toSql()` only this SQL statement is generated: `"select * from "orders""`, but not the additional constraint that I added in the global query scope.

Also, the greatest debugging tool of all time (`dd()` statement) is not being executed, which might be an indication that the booted method is not being called.

So what have I done wrong? I did exactly [what the documentation says](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#global-scopes). When does the booted() method get called?

Comment: toSql is a method inherited by Query Builder, not from Eloquent Builder, so Eloquent Builder functionalities like the boot method are not involved when you call toSql

Comment: @Berto99 So when is the booted() method eventually called? According to the documentation, it should be called when `all()` is called. But in my case even then the dd() is not executed

Comment: when you use Eloquent functionalities, it is called, when you use QueryBuilder functionalities, it's not. The "all" call you can see on the documentation is just an example, if you use with, where, wherehas, get, take, paginate ecc ecc, that boot method will be called

Comment: @Berto99 Thanks for your clarification. Unfortunately, I just tried Order::with('relation'), Order::get(), Order::paginate() and none of them was actually able to invoke booted(). You keep referring to `boot`, but the method in question is booted(). I know if I replace booted() with boot() everything will work. But I am just trying to understand the significance of the booted() method and it's relation to global query scope.

Comment: with which version of Laravel are you working with?

Comment: Version: 6.16.0

Comment: Ok, got it. 6.x doesn't support booted?

Comment: eeeexactlyyyyyyyyyyyyy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `boot` method name is changed to `booted` only in the last version of Laravel (`7.x`), so be aware of this, otherwise it won't work.

Keep in mind always to set the version of Laravel you are using on the documentation (on the top right corner there is a dropdown where you can select the version)